# TypeError: callback is not a function when downloading a Google Drive File

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

Im using the code from this example

https://gist.github.com/Daniel15/5994054

The picker returns a file and when i try to download it with this function

```
function downloadFile(file, callback) {
  if (file.downloadUrl) {
    var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', file.downloadUrl);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
    xhr.onload = function() {
      callback(xhr.responseText);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function() {
      callback(null);
    };
    xhr.send();
  } else {
    callback(null);
  }
}
```

It throws this error

TypeError: callback is not a function callback(null) filepicker.js(line 130)

Comment: how are you calling downloadFile, are you passing it a function? i.e downloadFile("file",function(){ //callback function });

Comment: onSelect: function(file) {
        console.log(file);
        downloadFile(file);
        alert('Selected ' + file.title);
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from your example call

```
    function initPicker() {
     var picker = new FilePicker({
         apiKey: 'AIzaSyB8a8yohsAyEz1eZEFgt2YE-tMgACYWnVs',
         clientId: 458068379722,
         buttonEl: document.getElementById('pick'),
         onSelect: function(file) {
             console.log(file);
             downloadFile(file);
             alert('Selected ' + file.title);
         }
     });
 }
```

you are not passing a callback function, either handle this by checking callback is a function in the downloadFile method before it tries to run it.....

```
 function downloadFile(file, callback) {
     if (file.downloadUrl) {
         var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
         var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhr.open('GET', file.downloadUrl);
         xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
         xhr.onload = function() {
             if (typeof callback == "function") {
                 callback(xhr.responseText);
             }
         };
         xhr.onerror = function() {
             if (typeof callback == "function") {
                 callback(null);
             }
         };
         xhr.send();
     } else {
         if (typeof callback == "function") {
                 callback(null);
             }
     }
 }
```

or provide a callback function.

```
  function initPicker() {
         var picker = new FilePicker({
             apiKey: 'AIzaSyB8a8yohsAyEz1eZEFgt2YE-tMgACYWnVs',
             clientId: 458068379722,
             buttonEl: document.getElementById('pick'),
             onSelect: function(file) {
                 console.log(file);
                 downloadFile(file, function(){
                        //do something when the file is donwloaded
                 });
                 alert('Selected ' + file.title);
             }
         });
     }
```

Comment: i added a callback function to my downloadfile with an alert, and with that i got rid of the error but it doesnt seem to do anything else i mean the file i picked is not being downloaded